# Application not able to install in Apple iWatch

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch

I have made an demo app for Apple Watch that is working in the simulator, but when i try to install it in Apple Watch, it gets cancelled automatically after 75% of the installation.

what should be the reason for it?

Comment: I am facing same issue with my I Watch, I am still stuck with same issue.

Comment: please let us know if you find any solution thank you :)

Comment: Have you add your watch in developer portal ?

Comment: ohh thank you for your suggestion,will check it soon and let you know :)

Comment: Have you checked the iPhone and Apple Watch console logs, to determine the reason for this issue? Questions which contain a specific error message are more useful to others, and if you search for that error message, you might even find an existing answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is able to resolve by adding UDID to provisioning profile of the App.